# Degeneracy of characters when searching for a specific sub-string

Tags: perl

I have the following script which searches for specified substrings within an input string (a DNA sequence). I was wondering if anybody could help out with being able to specify degeneracy of specific characters. For example, instead of searching for GATC (or anything consisting solely of G's, T's, A's and C's), I could instead search for GRTNA where R = A **or** G and where N = A, G, C **or** T. I would need to be able to specify quite a few of these in a long list within the script. Many thanks for any help or tips!

```
use warnings;
use strict;

#User Input
my $usage = "Usage (OSX Terminal): perl <$0> <FASTA File> <Results Directory + Filename>\n";

#Reading formatted FASTA/FA files
sub read_fasta {
    my ($in) = @_;
    my $sequence = "";

    while(<$in>) {
        my $line = $_;
        chomp($line);
        if($line =~ /^>/){ next }
        else { $sequence .= $line }
    }
    return(\$sequence);
}

#Scanning for restriction sites and length-output
open(my $in, "<", shift);

open(my $out, ">", shift);

my $DNA = read_fasta($in);

print "DNA is: \n $$DNA \n";
my $len = length($$DNA);
print "\n DNA Length is: $len \n";

my @pats=qw( GTTAAC );

for (@pats) {
    my $m = () = $$DNA =~ /$_/gi;
    print "\n Total DNA matches to $_ are: $m \n";
}

my $pat=join("|",@pats);

my @cutarr = split(/$pat/, $$DNA);

for (@cutarr) {
    my $len = length($_);
    print $out "$len \n";
}
close($out);
close($in);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GRTNA` would correspond to the pattern `G[AG]T[AGCT]A`.

It looks like you could do this by writing

```
for (@pats) {
  s/R/[AG]/g;
  s/N/[AGCT]/g;
}
```

before

```
my $pat = join '|', @pats;
my @cutarr = split /$pat/, $$DNA;
```

but I'm not sure I can help you with the requirement that *"I would need to be able to specify quite a few of these in a long list within the script"*. I think it would be best to put your sequences in a separate text file rather than embed the list directly into the program.

By the way, wouldn't it be simpler just to

```
return $sequence
```

from your `read_fasta` subroutine? Returning a reference just means you have to dereference it everywhere with `$$DNA`. I suggest that it should look like this

```
sub read_fasta {
  my ($fh) = @_;
  my $sequence;

  while (<$fh>) {
    unless (/^>/) {
      chomp;
      $sequence .= $_;
    }
  }

  return $sequence;
}
```

Comment: Great thank you! I had to move the degeneracy specification up the script slightly so that printing the number of matches functions. The FASTA subroutine was written by a colleague a rather long time ago but yes, I totally agree that your approach would be easier. Thanks again.